# Deploying WAR file to Jetty: server is running, but application didn't start

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

I got Spring Boot `2.2.7.RELEASE` application. Package it as `war` file and trying to deploy it locally with Jetty:

```
public static void startJetty() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    File warFile = new File("target/rest-service/my-rest-service.war");
    context.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
}
```

After this Jetty is up and running at `localhost:8080`, got no errors in log but it seems like the application didn't start. When I try to reach it the response is 404 NOT FOUND. Although I do see my application directories at `localhost:8080` like `/swagger-ui/` etc.

Comment: Why? Ditch this code, Spring Boot does that already for you. Basically you are working around Spring Boot with this code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need to launch this app before my code start working. How else can I launch Spring Boot jar or war from the java code?

Comment: Spring Boot does al that for you. Create an class, add `@SpringBootApplication` in your main do `SpringApplication.run` and Spring Boot will bootstrap Jetty for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I got maven module without Spring in it and got Spring Boot jar application in my /target folder. I need to launch it with pure Java code. Maybe something like Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar target/my-app.jar"); but also understand when it will up and ready to deal with.

Comment: Again you don't need that, Spring Boot does all that for you. Please read the documenation instead of working around SPring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop that code and let Spring Boot handle it.

Assuming you have an application class named `MyRestApplication` you need to have the following.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyRestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyRestApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Assuming you have Jetty as a dependency as well as `spring-boot-starter-web` you can just run this class.

You should also use the spring Boot plugin to create the war or jar and then you can just launch it.

`java -jar my-rest-service.war` and it will launch everything you need.

Comment: Thank you! java -jar my-rest-service.war works for me!